# How to execute a Maven build Java application

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am playing to Maven and tried to built a simple HellowWorld application.

This application uses Spring to libraries.

When I tried to run it, I run it through:
   \target\classes
with command:
   java -cp  HelloWorldApp

It has a long list of classpath dependencies.

I think maven must have some more clever ways to do this instead of listing a whole list of dependency libs.

Can someone help?

**Update:**

Thanks. I now have another question. I run the project using:
             mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.vaannila.HelloWorldApp"

However, my project uses a Spring config called beans.xml which is in the 
             \src\main\resources

When I run it, it says:

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:142)at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.jav
a:336)

How can I specify where to look the Spring config?

Many thanks

Comment: As for me, usually, I'm either build self-sustainable delivery, such as war, or jar with dependencies, or make custom assembly to produce zip containing all dependencies and some script to enumerate them in `-cp` argument to `java`.

Answer (score 3):

Run your application by issuing `mvn exec:java` at the command line, maven will take care of the rest including download of the maven exec plugin.

**EDIT** As for your updated question: It appears that maven did not copy your resources to the target folder, you can use the `maven-resources-plugin` to do that. This [link](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) should help you get this done.

Comment: Thanks. I now have another question. stated below

Comment: I recommend you ask your supplementary question as a separate question, and provide a bit more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you use IDE, such as eclipse +m2eclipse - it will calculate all dependencies from maven dependencies.

If you are running from command line use [Exec maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html)